# What's the recipe for an insulation amplifier for Furnace Mk2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I've installed the mod [Furnace Mk2](https://www.minecraftmods.com/furnace-mk2/).  It has pics for its recipes, but the one for the insulation amplifier is rather vague.  I've figured out that the corners are sand and I'm pretty sure the top and bottom center are smooth stone due to similarity with the recipe for the furnace itself.  But the middle row is a mystery!  I've tried iron blocks, white wool, clay blocks, quartz blocks...all to no avail.  All I can tell is that they are predominantly whitish gray.  The images shown are screenshots and so have no hover text to indicate what kind of block each one is.

You'd think the crafting table would tell me, but something is wrong with the release of recipes and they don't come up until you use them.  Perhaps that's why they posted the pics.

Does anyone have any information about this recipe?  I'd really appreciate the help!  It has otherwise been a great mod so far.

Comment: white concrete maybe? It looks too white to be anything else (except maybe quartz, which you tried)

Comment: also, are you sure the others are smooth stone? they look to me like they might be clay

Comment: Note that this question is not asking for technical support. Vote to leave open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked the images, and I'm pretty sure the top and bottom blocks are clay blocks, and the center row is white concrete (or maybe white concrete powder). There is definitely no smooth stone involved; I compared the images to the furnace crafting recipe images and unlike the smooth stone for the furnace, the blocks in the insulation amplifier recipe have no dark borders.

Comment: You are a wonderful help!  I'd never worked with concrete before so I didn't even think of it!  And I had tried clay, but that didn't work because of the lack of concrete!  (And it was a full on concrete block rather than powder.)  Thank you so much!