# What's the recipe for a thermal magnifier for Furnace Mk2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

As I've mentioned in my [question here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/397643/whats-the-recipe-for-an-insulation-amplifier-for-furnace-mk2) I've installed the mod [Furnace Mk2](https://www.minecraftmods.com/furnace-mk2/). It has pics for its recipes, but the one for the thermal magnifier is not completely clear.  It has three black blocks on the bottom row, but I can't figure out what they are.  I've tried:

- cobbled deepslate
- deepslate
- deepslate tiles
- deepslate bricks
- blackstone
- polished blackstone
- polished blackstone bricks
- basalt
- smooth basalt
- polished basalt
- black wool
- black terracotta
- black concrete powder
- black concrete
- block of coal
- obsidian

I'm pretty sure from zooming the image that it isn't a cracked or chiseled variant of the above.  I've looked at every blackish block in the list at the [*unofficial* wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block).  I'm at a loss here.

Again, as mentioned in my earlier post, there is something wrong with recipe releases and it doesn't show the recipe in the book until you've already crafted the thing.

Can some kind soul who's using this mod or just knowledgeable about blocks help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this video](https://youtu.be/8gDOyCzlHN0?t=79) those are:

- 1x Lava bucket
- 4x Nether bricks
- 1x Magma block
- 3x Blackstones

Comment: You rock!  I'm not a video kind of person.  I learn best from text.  I was using netherite ingots!  All that time in the Nether for nothing.  I had netherack coming out my ears.  **rolls eyes**  Thank you very much!

Comment: I also decided to watch the video and it answered my last question on how to get the XP out of the attuned crystal.  I was just clicking it in inventory rather than holding it and clicking that way!  **smacks forehead**  Thanks again!  So much!

Comment: Glad to help! I usually prefer text too, but there's always a video tutorial when needed, expecially about Minecraft :)